# Table cell doesn't obey vertical-align CSS declaration when it contains a floated element

Tags: css

I am trying to create a table, where each cell contains a big floated h1 on the left side, and a larger amount of small text to the right of the big text, vertically centered.

However, the small text is showing up at the top of each cell, despite that it has a "vertical-align: middle" declaration. When I remove the big floated element, everything looks fine. I tested it in recent versions of IE, Firefox, and Safari, and this happened in every case.

Why is this happening? Does anyone know of a way around it? Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<title>vertical-align test</title>
<style type="text/css">
td {
    border: solid black 1px; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 12px}
h1 {
    font-size: 40px; float: left}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>1</h1>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</td>
        <td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Notice that the small text in the first cell is at the top for some reason, but the text in the 2nd cell is vertically centered.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem... now for the solution...

Comment: +1, interesting problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's because the `<h1>` element is a **block element** and the casual text is **inline**. So you have to force `<h1>` to behave like an inline element, which by the way, means **no floating**.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<title>vertical-align test</title>
<style type="text/css">
td {
    border: solid black 1px; font-size: 12px}
h1{
   display:inline;font-size: 40px;vertical-align: middle;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><h1>1</h1>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</td>
     <td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Oh and BTW - do **NOT** use tables for layout. It's old, it's ugly, it's not worth it.

Comment: Good job. Don't know why that didn't work for me... probably I was missing the `align:middle` part.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it seems to work. However, if the small text wraps onto more than one line, it looks funny. Instead of being vertically aligned, it goes under the h1. I can post an example if you want.

Comment: By default, text will wrap around floated elements.

Comment: I generally don't like using tables for layout, but I am trying to make the boxes have equal height, and it really seems like the simplest way to do this that works reliably in all the popular browsers.

Comment: Glad it worked but please choose some answer or it'll keep coming up as 'Unanswered'

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no clue why it does that.

But could you change it to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<title>vertical-align test</title>
<style type="text/css">
td {
    border: solid black 1px; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 12px}
h1 {
    font-size: 40px; float: left}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <table><tr><td style='border: 0px;'><h1>1</h1></td><td style='border: 0px;'>
           The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</td></tr></table></td>
        <td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

I know it's ugly - but it works.

Comment: I tried that and it works. I would prefer a more elegant way, but I may have to do this.